# Convert pandas column with multiple timezones to single timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, timezone

### Problem

I've got a column in a pandas DataFrame that contains timestamps with timezones. There are two different timezones present in this column, and I need to ensure that there's only one. Here's the output of the end of the column:

```
260003    2019-05-21 12:00:00-06:00
260004    2019-05-21 12:15:00-06:00
Name: timestamp, Length: 260005, dtype: object
```

For what it's worth, the timestamps vary between `-06:00` and `-07:00`, and have the following output:

`datetime.datetime(2007, 10, 1, 1, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600))` for `-06:00`
`datetime.datetime(2007, 11, 17, 5, 15, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -25200))` for `-07:00`

### What I've Done

I've been trying to use tz.localize and tz.convert, which have worked fine in the past, but I suppose that data has only ever had one timezone. E.g., if I do:

`df['timestamp'].dt.tz_localize('MST', ambiguous='infer').dt.tz_convert('MST')`

I get:

```
ValueError: Array must be all same time zone

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

### Question

Is there a way to convert these to MST? Or any timezone, really? I guess I could break up the DataFrame by timezone (not 100% sure how, but I imagine it's possible) and act on chunks of it, but I figured I'd ask to see if there's a smarter solution out there. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2019-05-21 12:00:00-06:00',
                                '2019-05-21 12:15:00-07:00']})
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)

df.timestamp.dt.tz_localize('MST')
```

works fine and gives:

```
0   2019-05-21 18:00:00-07:00
1   2019-05-21 19:15:00-07:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, MST]
```

It is not what you expect?

---

Edit: Thanks to @G.Anderson's comment, I tried the different data with timezone-aware timestamps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':[pd.to_datetime('2019-05-21 12:00:00').tz_localize('MST'),
                         pd.to_datetime('2019-05-21 12:15:00').tz_localize('EST')]})
```

then

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
```

did give the same error. Then I added `utc=True`:

```
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, utc=True)

# df.timestamp
# 0   2019-05-21 19:00:00+00:00
# 1   2019-05-21 17:15:00+00:00
# Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]

df.timestamp.dt.tz_convert('MST')
```

works fine and gives:

```
0   2019-05-21 12:00:00-07:00
1   2019-05-21 10:15:00-07:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, MST]
```

Comment: Were your inputs given different timezone attributes before you ran the `localize` step, as in OPs example?

Comment: @G.Anderson correct me if I'm wrong, but as I understand from OP's *the timestamps vary between `-06:00` and `-07:00`*, yes, the toy data in my answer/code have two different timezone attributes.

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks for the comment. I did try what you suggested and update the answer.

Comment: @QuangHoang Could you please explain what `utc=True` means?

Comment: @S.V that option automatically localizes the timestamps to `utc`.

Comment: @QuangHoang So, is it equivalent to `df.timestamp.dt.tz_convert('UTC')`? In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56245503/6461882), I tried `series.dt.tz_convert('UTC', utc=True)` and got the same exceptions.

Comment: @S.V I bet it is. `pd.to_datetime` must add some magic to it, however.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I didn't realize the `utc=True` was meant as a `to_datetime` parameter. Thank you!

Comment: this should be cleaned up I think. The correct method is to use `pd.to_datetime` with `utc=True` and then `dt.tz_convert` if you know the origin time zone. In contrast, not using utc=True effectively doubles the UTC offset if `dt.tz_localize` is called.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# input data
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(data=
    [pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01 00:00:00').tz_localize('MST'),
     pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01 01:10:00').tz_localize('UTC')])
print(series)
```

gives

```
0    2019-01-01 00:00:00-07:00
1    2019-01-01 01:10:00+00:00
dtype: object
```

Indeed,

```py
series.dt.tz_convert('MST')
```

gives *"ValueError: Array must be all same time zone"* and *"ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True"*. So, it seems, you have to do it in a non-vectorized way:

```py
new_series = pd.Series(index=series.index,
    data=[x.tz_convert('MST') for x in series])
print(new_series)
```

gives

```
0   2019-01-01 00:00:00-07:00
1   2018-12-31 18:10:00-07:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, MST]
```

Edit: if @QuangHoang is right (i.e. *"the option automatically localizes the timestamps to utc"*, double check it!) about the meaning of `pd.to_datetime(..., utc=True)`, then the following solution will also work:

```py
new_series = pd.to_datetime(series, utc=True).dt.tz_convert('MST')
print(new_series)
```

gives

```
0   2019-01-01 00:00:00-07:00
1   2018-12-31 18:10:00-07:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, MST]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I gave the answer to @QuangHoang, but I genuinely appreciate your discussion with them to figure things out.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a series `a` with multiple different timezones. 
We expect `a.tz_convert()` or `a.tz_localize()` work but they don't.
The solution is to use the `apply` method. 
Please see the examples below:

```
> a
0    2019-10-04 16:30:00+02:00
1    2019-10-07 16:00:00-04:00
2    2019-09-24 08:30:00-07:00
Name: localized, dtype: object

> a.iloc[0]
Timestamp('2019-10-04 16:30:00+0200', tz='Europe/Amsterdam')

> a.apply(lambda x: x.tz_convert('America/Los_Angeles'))
0   2019-10-04 07:30:00-07:00
1   2019-10-07 13:00:00-07:00
2   2019-09-24 08:30:00-07:00
Name: localized, dtype: datetime64[ns, America/Los_Angeles]

# Make it tz-naive, i.e. remove tz info, note you lose information here, you might want to store tz-info in another series before the conversion.
> a.apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize(None))
0   2019-10-04 16:30:00
1   2019-10-07 16:00:00
2   2019-09-24 08:30:00
Name: localized, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```