# pd.to_datetime() not properly converting the type to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am looking to parse data with multiple timezones on a single column. I am using the `pd.to_datetime` function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2019-05-21 12:00:00-06:00', '2019-05-21 12:15:00-07:00']})
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df.info()
```

This results in:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------     --------------  ----- 
 0   timestamp  2 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 144.0+ bytes
```

I did some testing and noticed that the same does not happen when the offsets are all the same:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2019-05-21 12:00:00-06:00', '2019-05-21 12:15:00-06:00']})
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype                                 
---  ------     --------------  -----                                 
 0   timestamp  2 non-null      datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-360)]
dtypes: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-360)](1)
memory usage: 144.0 bytes
```

If this error is confirmed, it will have direct implication over the datetime accessors, but it also breaks some compatibility (or assumed compatibilities) with library that operate conversions on the types. The `pd.to_datetime()` is successfully able to convert everything to a `datetime.datetime`, but, libraries like `pyarrow` will apply a fixed tz offset on the column.

Based on many questions on StackOverflow (ex: [Convert pandas column with multiple timezones to single timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245036/convert-pandas-column-with-multiple-timezones-to-single-timezone)) this was not the behavior of pandas in previous versions.

I am on pandas `1.2.4` (I updated from `1.2.2` that shows the same). Python `3.7.9`.

Should I report this as a GitHub issue?

Comment: what is the error you speak of / what is your expected output? As far as I can tell, you have mixed UTC offsets in your input - if you want dtype datetime64[ns], use `utc=True` and then `tz_convert` to the desired time zone.

Comment: Have the same issue on pandas v1.2.1, following accepted answer in linked question (using `utc=True` in `pd.to_datetime`) seems to work fine.

Comment: That’s correct, utc=True will force pandas to apply the offsets, however, then the information about it is lost. My expected behavior would be, the possibility of calling the dt accessor to the result. In my specific case, I want to have a column with the local time stamp and another with the utc time stamp. I can manually strip the string of the offset, but as these dates follow the ISO standard, real utc have a Z, which will make my approach fail. Additionally I have seen pyarrow converting a column with different offsets to a column with the same offset for everyone.

Comment: A lambda function would allow me to retain the offset, but I was wondering why the dt accessor is not available in this specific case.

Comment: the dt accessor is only available for pandas built-in datetime dtype, which is basically [numpy's datetime](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html) - which by itself does not store time zone information. So the tz needs to be stored separately. Now if you have mixed offsets, you have to store them along with the elements of the series - which is why pandas falls back to using Python's datetime class objects - which don't allow to use the dt accessor ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to keep the original timestamp column with the offset (to not lose that info) and work with UTC (`utc=True`). If you know the time zone that put that offset on the data, you could also `tz_convert`.

Ex / cleaned-up version of the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56245036/10197418):

```
import pandas as pd

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2019-05-21 12:00:00-06:00', 
                                '2019-02-21 12:15:00-07:00']})

# assuming we know the origin time zone
zone = 'America/Boise'

# skip the .dt.tz_convert(zone) part if you don't have the specific zone
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], utc=True).dt.tz_convert(zone)

df
                   timestamp                  datetime
0  2019-05-21 12:00:00-06:00 2019-05-21 12:00:00-06:00
1  2019-02-21 12:15:00-07:00 2019-02-21 12:15:00-07:00

df['datetime']
0   2019-05-21 12:00:00-06:00
1   2019-02-21 12:15:00-07:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns, America/Boise]
```